# Check double booking feature with SharePoint online calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

In SharePoint online "Group Work Lists" feature is hidden. so i have activated referring below link and double booking functionality working properly.

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/588685/reservationplusofplusresourcesplusinplussharepoint

but the problem is that the "Group Work Lists" feature and also other group site template feature not available so it might happen that it can be removed in future so i don't want to use this feature for check double booking feature in calendar.

So is there any way to achieve "Check double booking" functionality using javascript/jquery or other ways?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try this link
http://spjsblog.com/2012/02/25/spjs-resource-management-no-more-double-booking/
He is using JavaScript.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer. A link-only answer will render useless to future readers if the link breaks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119368)